# how to get a mail embed image in javamail imap?

Tags: image, embed, jakarta-mail, imap

I want to get a mail embed image in javamail imap .How to do that?
Only image save as local(D:\) and then replace its path in mail client? inputstream is ok? 
Any suggestion?
Thanks advanced.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:\\"
                + part.getFileName());
        InputStream in = part.getInputStream();
        byte[] by = new byte[8192];
        int x = 0;
        System.out.println(x);
        while ((x = in.read(by)) != -1) {
            fos.write(by);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        temp = temp + 1;
        tempname = tempname + part.getFileName() + "~-";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question.  You want to save an image into a file?  Use the [MimeBodyPart.saveFile method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#saveFile%28java.io.File%29).